# How can i Downgrade my Lg G Flex 2?

Tags: downgrade

Is it possible for me to downgrade to kitkat... If it is can someone please tell me how. I am on a Lg G Flex 2, currently running on Lolipop 5.1.1..il leave further specs below.

**Specs:**

Lolipop: 5.1.1
Kernel: 3.10.49
Build: LMY47S
Software Version: V15c- TWN-XX
Model Number: LG-H959
Hardware Version: Rev.1.0

Answer (score 0):

No you simply can't. The phone is released with Lollipop (5.0) as its initial version. And even if there was once KitKat available, chances are you can't downgrade to it due to bootloader restrictions.